# calling function using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

In my HTML page I've the following ul:

```
 <ul id="inFile2"></ul>
```

and in my JavaScript page, I've this function

```
function handleFileSelect(event) {
 var files = event.target.files; // FileList object

 console.log(files);
 // files is a FileList of File objects. display first file name
 file = files[0];

 console.log(file);
 if (file) {

     readInputFile(file);
     console.log(file);

 }
}
```

I want to call the function in the ul. How could that happen? this is what I have tried so far

```
el=document.getElementById('inFile2');
el.on("change",handleFileSelect);
```

but gives me an error. What is the correct coding to call that function in the ul?

Comment: What's the error message?

Comment: "I want to call the function in the ul". Hmmm what do you mean? In response to which event? Click? BTW what's "el"? Where it comes from?

Comment: The `change` event does not fire on `ul` elements… if that's what `el` is.

Comment: A <ul> element cannot have a FileList object, and it also does not have a 'change' event

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function

Comment: 1. `el` is DOM object not a jQuery object. 2. Read @Andy comment once again

Comment: Are you defining the function before set the handler?

Comment: yes im defining the function before setting the handler,ok how am I supposed to call that function in the ul,the aim is that this function calls another function ( readInputFile(file);) to display it in the ul

Answer (score 1):

Issues that I see with your code:

1. `el` is a DOM object, not a [jQuery object](http://api.jquery.com/Types/#jQuery). If you do `el instanceof $`, you will get `false`.
2. A `change` event does not fire on `ul` elements.
3. There is no `files` property on an [`HTMLUListElement`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/HTMLUListElement), if that's what `el` is representing.

### HTML

```
<input type=file id=inFile2>
```

### JavaScript

```
var $el = $('#inFile2');
$el.on('change', handleFileSelect);

// Alternatively
var el = document.getElementById('inFile2');
$(el).on('change', handleFileSelect);
```

With a file input (i.e. `<input type=file>`), there is a `files` property that returns a `FileList`. See [`HTMLInputElement`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/HTMLInputElement) for more details.

See [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Qass7/) for example.

Comment: The code I provided should call the function upon changing the file in the input assuming that the function is defined before the `.on()` statement.

Comment: i know about input type="file" but this will make the user browse the file, my program requirements allows the project to read the file from a folder and place it in the ul that's why i cant use the type="file"

Comment: If you're running this program in a browser, you cannot automatically read files from the user's filesystem because this would be a major security flaw.

Comment: the error is not showing anymore when trying your code but it is not firing

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are looking for?

**Fiddle:** [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sid_m/fx7ug/1/)

```
$("#inFile2").click(function(){
   handleFileSelect('your_value')
});

function handleFileSelect(event) {
alert("called");
//your code here

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I can't see any reason of using jQuery .. I'd use pure JavaScript:

```
var el = document.getElementById("inFile2");
el.addEventListener("change", handleFileSelect, false);
```

jQuery is just another JS library which slows down script execution - not much, but does...

see [Javascript Event Listening](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget.addEventListener)

Comment: thanks for your help but as I said earlier I dont want to choose file, I want the file to be shown in the inFile2 directly reading from folder not by choosing